# Pandas Dataframe Reshaping to contain comparison data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe constructed as such. I have a query I run, which returns results for the data below.

```
[
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2020, 
        1, 
        245, 
  ),
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2019, 
        1, 
        215, 
  ),
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2018, 
        1, 
        205, 
  ),
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2020, 
        2, 
        245, 
  ),
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2019, 
        2, 
        215, 
  ),
  (
        3148, 
        'test account', 
        2018, 
        2, 
        215, 
  ),
```

]

I define columns.

```
    columns = [
    "id",
    "account_name",
    "year",
    "quarter",
    "cost",
]
```

I create a dataframe using query result and columns above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(query_result, columns=columns).round(2)
```

I would like to format the data so that each array will contain a year's data and the previous year's `cost` value in that quarter as such. To be clear, does pandas have a slick way to add the previous year's data in the same quarter to each array? I have tried the following.

```
    for year in df['year'].unique():
      for q in df['quarter'].unique():
        print(year)
        print(q)
        rslt_df = df[(df['year'] == year - 1) & (df['quarter'] == q)]
        df["prev_year_cost"] = rslt_df[cost]
```

However, this approach doesn't quite yield the results I am looking for, an it feels pretty costly with the nested loops and I think pandas can do better if I knew better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this will be solved with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), or with [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)

```
# Each year will have a previous year cost in a new column
df['prev_year_cost'] = df['cost'].shift(-1)

     id  account_name  year  quarter  cost  prev_year_cost
0  3148  test account  2020        1   245           215.0
1  3148  test account  2019        1   215           205.0
2  3148  test account  2018        1   205           245.0
3  3148  test account  2020        2   245           215.0
4  3148  test account  2019        2   215           215.0
5  3148  test account  2018        2   215             NaN
```

---

```
# Groups by quarter and returns previous year's cost
df['prev_year_cost_grouped'] = df.groupby('quarter')['cost'].shift(-1)

     id  account_name  year  quarter  cost  prev_year_cost_grouped
0  3148  test account  2020        1   245                   215.0
1  3148  test account  2019        1   215                   205.0
2  3148  test account  2018        1   205                     NaN
3  3148  test account  2020        2   245                   215.0
4  3148  test account  2019        2   215                   215.0
5  3148  test account  2018        2   215                     NaN
```

Hopefully this will help.